# google sheet protection fail when moving cells

Tags: google-sheets

I was making tests to find a solution to protect "unprotected" cells in a protected sheet against format, validation etc. changes. and I have found several problems. I would appreciate some help to do that, but I'd like to share first the most extrange problem I've found:

When I move one of the unprotected cell over another, apart from losing format, validation, etc, the major problem is that the protection itself is lost !!

For example, having a sheet protected except B7 and B10, if I move B7 over B10 from an editor account (not the owner), the protection in B7 is lost! while the protection in B10 is maintained.
Going back to  the owner account I Check the protected exceptions and seem to be the originals, but if I reload the sheet I can see they are changed, and the exception in B7 has changed to a new range B10:A9 (yes, written in such order).
If I don't validate this protection, cell A9 remains protected in the editor account, but if I validate the protection from the owner account without changing, I can see that the range B10:A9 changes to the normal order A9:B10 and then from the editor account I can access to cells A9 to B10.

Is this a known thing? Am I doing something bad?

Edited: link to a demo sheet with edition access to anyone with the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FzAMms7Wy93Nk-MOoxaRQzHSJZpbpWmcgB5FPUH_sjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet or screenshots of when and how this happens for further investigation?

Comment: I have a sheet where I have simulated the fail, but it is in spanish. I think it's easier to reproduce with my instructions. If you can't reproduce I could make a simpler sheet in english